# Lyapunov functions and basins of attraction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

\begin{align}
    x' &= -x^3 + x^5 + (x^4)(y^5)\\[.7em]
    y' &= -8y^3 + y^5 - 10(y^4)(x^5)
\end{align}
$(0,0)$ is obviously a critical point of the system, and we are given that it is asymptotically stable, but have to show it.

I have tried to make a Lyapunov function $V(x,y) = ax^2 + cy^2$, with $a,c > 0$ but I am having trouble to prove that $\frac{d}{dt} V(x,y)$ is negative definite. I get some complicated polynomial I can't use logic to finalize. How can I change the Lyapunov to come up with a meaningful conclusion?

\begin{align}
    \frac{d}{dt}V(x,y) = 2ax(-3x^2 + 5x^4 + 4x^3y^5) + 2cy(-24y^2+5y^4-40y^3x^5)\\[.7em]
\end{align}

Comment: Please write down more details of your attempt. What are $a$ and $b$, what is the derivative expression? Edit the question to add this.

Comment: @ LutzL added your remarks

Comment: Please consider that $\frac{d}{dt}V(x(t),y(t))=\partial_xV·x'+\partial_yV·y'$, there is no further derivative of the system functions involved.

Comment: You can certainly prove local asymptotic stability of the origin since the lower order terms dominate therein. Also my first impression is that this system is not globally asymptotically stable so your search for a global Lyapunov function may not be possible.

Comment: @CTNT yes you are correct in that it is not globally asymptotically stable. It's regarding local stability and its basin of attraction. I understand that the lower terms dominate from the answer below, but how can you choose a and c in V(x,y)?

Comment: The simple selection $V=x^2+y^2$ will do the job.

Comment: @CTNT using $V = x^2+y^2$ results in something like, $V' = -6(x^3+8y^3) + 10(x^5+y^5) + 8x^4y^4(y-8x)$, is this what I need to look at to draw a conclusion?

Comment: I will post an answer.

Comment: @CTNT Ok I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 
$$V(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)$$
we have
$$\dot{V}=-x^4-8y^4+x^6+y^6-9y^5x^5\\
\leq -(1-x^2-|xy|)x^4-8(1-(1/8)y^2-|xy|)y^4$$
Thus if we define the region (neighborhood of the origin)
$$\Omega:=\left\{(x,y)|(x^2+|xy|<1)\textrm{ and }\frac{1}{8}y^2+|xy|<1\right\}$$
we have that $$\dot{V}(x,y)<0\qquad \forall (x,y)\in\Omega\neq 0$$
Now if we choose the level set 
$$\Omega_0:=\left\{(x,y)|V(x,y)<\frac{1}{4}\right\}\subseteq \Omega$$
we also have that 
$$\dot{V}(x,y)<0\qquad \forall (x,y)\in\Omega_0\neq 0$$
Therefore every solution that starts within $\Omega_0$ remains therein and asymptotically converges to the origin ($V$ is strictly decreasing).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: choose $a$ and $c$ so the terms in $x^5 y^5$ cancel.  Note that for $x$ near $0$, lower powers of $x$ dominate higher powers, and similarly for $y$.

Comment: Could you explain more on how to choose a and c? I think that is where I am having the most difficulty.

Comment: You should get $\frac{d}{dt}V(x,y) = 2ax(-x^3 + x^5 + x^4y^5) + 2cy(-8y^3+y^5-10x^5y^4)$. Then the cancellation should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be handled with an optimization procedure, having in mind that generally is a non convex problem. The result depends on the test Lyapunov function used so we will generalize to a quadratic Lyapunov function

$$
V(p) = p^{\dagger}\cdot M\cdot p = a x^2+b x y + c y^2,\ \ \ p = (x,y)^{\dagger}
$$

and

$$
f(p) = \{-x^3 + x^5 + x^4 y^5, -8 y^3 + y^5 - 10 x^5 y^4\}
$$
with $a>0,c>0, a b-b^2 > 0$ to assure positivity on $M$. We will assure a set involving the origin $Q_{\dot V}$ such that $\dot V(Q_{\dot V}) < 0$. The optimization process will be used to guarantee a maximal $Q_{\dot V}$.

After determination of $\dot V = 2 p^{\dagger}\cdot M\cdot f(p)$ we follow with a change of variables

$$
\cases{
x = r\cos\theta\\
y = r\sin\theta
}
$$

so $\dot V = \dot L(a,b,c,r,\theta)$. The next step is to make a sweep on $\theta$ calculating

$$
S(a,b,c, r)=\{\dot V(a,b,c,r,k\Delta\theta\},\ \ k = 0,\cdots, \frac{2\pi}{\Delta\theta}
$$

and then the optimization formulation follows as

$$
\max_{a,b,c,r}r\ \ \ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \ \ a > 0, c> 0, a c -b^2 > 0, \max S(a,b,c,r) \le -\gamma
$$

with $\gamma > 0$ a margin control number.

Follows a MATHEMATICA script which implements this procedure in the present case.

```
f = {-x^3 + x^5 + x^4 y^5, -8 y^3 + y^5 - 10 x^5 y^4};
V = a x^2 + 2 b x y + c y^2;
dV = Grad[V, {x, y}].f /. {x -> r Cos[t], y -> r Sin[t]};
rest = Max[Table[dV, {t, -Pi, Pi, Pi/30}]] < -0.2;
rests = Join[{rest}, {r > 0, a > 0, c > 0, a c - b^2 > 0}];
sols = NMinimize[Join[{-r}, rests], {a, b, c, r}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
rest /. sols[[2]]

dV0 = Grad[V, p].f /. sols[[2]]
V0 = V /. sols[[2]]
r0 = 1.5;
rmax = r /. sols[[2]];
gr0 = StreamPlot[f, {x, -r0, r0}, {y, -r0, r0}];
gr1a = ContourPlot[dV0, {x, -r0, r0}, {y, -r0, r0}, ContourShading -> None, Contours -> 80];
gr1b = ContourPlot[dV0 == 0, {x, -r0, r0}, {y, -r0, r0}, ContourStyle -> Blue];
gr2 = ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == rmax^2, {x, -r0, r0}, {y, -r0, r0}, ContourStyle -> {Red, Dashed}];
Show[gr0, gr1a, gr1b, gr2]
```

Follows a plot showing in black the level sets $Q_{\dot V}$ an in blue the trace of $\dot V = 0$. In dashed red is shown the largest circular set $\delta = 0.99992$ defining the maximum attraction basin for the given test Lyapunov function's family.

[image]